# `Server has closed the connection` when usnig two PrismaClients

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a project with Prisma+NestJS. My database is a master+replication PostgresSQL server with pgBouncer
It's executed in local server but `Server has closed the connection` happened for some customers when published. This error happened for different tables. This is just an example:

```
Invalid `this.prisma.readClient.customer.findUnique()` invocation in /usr/src/app/dist/src/modules/global/guards/auth-guard.js
54 const customer = await this.prisma.readClient.customer.findUnique( 
Server has closed the connection.
```

Connection Strings look like this:

```
DATABASE_WRITE_URL="postgresql://user:******@[masterip]:5432/database?schema=public&pgbouncer=true"
DATABASE_READ_URL="postgresql://user:******:@[replicaip]:5432/stage-v2-panel?schema=public&pgbouncer=true"
```

PrismaService file:

```js
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService implements OnModuleInit {
  readClient: PrismaClient;
  writeClient: PrismaClient;

  constructor() {
    this.readClient = new PrismaClient({
      datasources: {db: {url: process.env.DATABASE_READ_URL}},
    });
    this.writeClient = new PrismaClient({
      datasources: {db: {url: process.env.DATABASE_WRITE_URL}},
    });
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.readClient.$connect();
    await this.writeClient.$connect();
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.readClient.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
    this.writeClient.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you enable logging to see if you get any more information about error? https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/logging

Comment: Did you try to log in `enableShutdownHooks` to see if it's this function that is triggered?